# awk to filter rows where at least two columns have minimum value?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file with 4 columns and >1 million rows with scores between 0 and 100. I am capable of filtering the file to keep rows where at least one column has a minimum value of 20 with a code that looks like the one below, using awk and OR operators (In reality my file has 50 columns so the code I use goes all the way to $50 >= 20).

```
awk '{if (($1 >= 20) || ($2 >=20) || ($3 >= 20) || ($4 >= 20)) print $0 }' file
```

But I would now like to filter rows where at least TWO columns have a minimum value of 20. I cannot think of an AND operator that would satisfy this criteria. Could someone please recommend any way to achieve this? Perhaps there is a solution that does not use awk?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you update your question with sample input and expected output.

Comment: I hope that you don't SERIOUSLY write expressions for all the columns up to $50 explicitly!!!!

Comment: @user1934428 Sadly I do because I am a big noob and because it works :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Perhaps there is a solution that does not use awk?

`perl` to the rescue!

```sh
$ cat input.txt
1 2 3 4
30 5 6 60
7 8 9 10
11 100 12 120 13
$ perl -ane 'print if (grep { $_ >= 20 } @F) >= 2' input.txt
30 5 6 60
11 100 12 120 13
```

Split each line into fields based on whitespace like `awk` does, then filter those fields to just those that are greater than or equal to 20. If there's at least 2 such fields, print the entire line.

Comment: This is very neat! Thank you! Would you expect it to work through tab-delimited fields or only whitespace?

Comment: I tested it through tab-delimited fields and it works perfectly! Thanks so much.

Comment: @DanS autosplit (the `-a` option) splits on any whitespace by default. To specifically split on tabs, add `-F "\t"`. (The similarity to awk is entirely intentional)

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Fair warning tested with small samples only, didn't test it on huge file or so.

```
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i>=20)  { count++ }
    if(count==2){ print;
                  count=0
                  fflush()
                  next
    }
  }
}' Input_file
```